# Show total number of unique values and individual unique values count for all the columns in a dataframe in python

Tags: python

**I have a dataframe say df -**

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({
                  'name' : ['abc', 'def', 'ghi', 'jkl'], 
                  'age' : [24, 22, 47, 52],
                  'gender' : ['M', 'F', 'F', 'M'], 
                  'project' : ['new', 'old', 'new', 'new']})
print(df)

  name  age gender project
0  abc   24      M     new
1  def   22      F     old
2  ghi   47      F     new
3  jkl   52      M     new
```

I want to get the total no. of unique values for every column and also list down the unique values with their count for every categorical column something like below.

**my output -**

```
name : 4
unique values : abc(1), def(1), ghi(1), jkl(1)
gender : 2
unique values : M(2), F(2)
project : 2
unique values : new(3), old(1)
```

Comment: use `len(set(data))` to count number of unique values. data is every value in the dict

Comment: `for c in df: print(df[c].value_counts())` + adjust output formatting

Comment: I didnt get the output in my desired format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not very elegant.. but

```
def unique_in_df(df):
    out = {}
    for col in df.columns:
        out[col] = {}
        unique = df[col].unique()
        for u in unique:
            out[col][u] = df[col].value_counts()[u]

    return out
        
output = unique_in_df(df)
```

gives in output:

```
{'name': {'abc': 1, 'def': 1, 'ghi': 1, 'jkl': 1},
 'age': {24: 1, 22: 1, 47: 1, 52: 1},
 'gender': {'M': 2, 'F': 2},
 'project': {'new': 3, 'old': 1}}
```

If you literally want your output-like printed to screen:

```
def unique_in_df(df):
    out = {}
    for col in df.columns:
        out[col] = {}
        unique = df[col].unique()
        for u in unique:
            out[col][u] = df[col].value_counts()[u]
            
    for k, v in out.items():
        print(f'{k}: {len(v)}')
        print('unique values :', end=' ')
        for k1, v1 in v.items():
            print(f'{k1}({v1}),', end=' ')
        print()
```

gives you exactly what you requested.

If you want to save the output you can redirect it to a txt file for example:

```
import sys
original_stdout = sys.stdout
with open('filename.txt', 'w') as f:  
    sys.stdout = f 
    unique_in_df(df)
    sys.stdout = original_stdout
```

Comment: Sir thanks a lot, you saved me, I spent few hours for this., may god bless you.

Comment: Sir just an add on to this- is it possible to make it downlodable in the same format? just like we download csv or excel. but csv or excel will disturb the format. Any suggestion regarding this.

Comment: @KReEd sure it is possible. you can convert the output in a dataframe instead of printing it and the un the pandas method .to_excel()

Comment: Sir is it possible to get the exact output(as I have requested in qstn and you have answered) in the same format in a text file?the problem is through every iteration the value is printed and its difficult to store somewhere.

Comment: I think you need to study some basics first, otherwise, you're just asking us to do your work.. btw today I'll help you. I've added to the previous answer what you need. Cheers

Comment: Thanks sir, btw i have acheived it with file=open('filename','w')' & then file.write('required values'). added wherever required.

Answer (score 0):

> You can use "value_counts" to count the element frequency and "to_dict" to collect the data in a dictionair

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'name' : ['abc', 'def', 'ghi', 'jkl'], 
                  'age' : [24, 22, 47, 52],
                  'gender' : ['M', 'F', 'F', 'M'], 
                  'project' : ['new', 'old', 'new', 'new']})
for (columnName, columnData) in df.iteritems():
    print(df[columnName].value_counts().to_dict())
```